# Save XLS Using Interop Excel

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

**The Current Setup:**

So, I can use the following code to save a file as an XLS:

```
_myWorkbook.SaveAs("FileName.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal)
```

I can also use the following code to save a file as an XLSX (Since I use Office 2010):

```
_myWorkbook.SaveAs("FileName.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault)
```

**The Issue:**

I have tried  (unsuccessfully) to save the file as an XLSX using the following code:

```
_myWorkbook.SaveAs("FileName.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12)
```

Why does this not work? Last I checked, Excel 12 was Excel 2007 (a version that supports XLSX). Am I missing something?

(For those interested, I get a `This extension can not be used with the selected file type` error)

Comment: is there a macro in the excel file ?

Comment: Does it work with a .xls extension?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: There is not. Just data on multiple tabs.

Comment: @Sorax: It does...but when the file is opened, there is a `The document is not in the format the extension says it is in. Do you trust it?` dialog that I'd rather avoid.

Comment: I haven't used the 2010 interop, I've switched to the OpenXML SDK, but I'm familiar with prior interops and I'm at a loss. What you're doing should work. I wish I could help.

Comment: is it ok to save it as XLS as long as you don't get the message ?

Comment: Are you creating a new file from scratch or opening an existing one and updating it? What format is the file you are opening (if that is what you are doing)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually `XlFileFormat.xlExcel12` is Excel 12.0 binary format (`xlsb`) , for OpenXML (i.e. `xlsx`) you need to use `XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook` enum value.

For a complete reference [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279%28v=office.12%29.aspx).